# How to change cpu frequency from assembly (from windows device driver)

Tags: c, windows, assembly

i have seen cpufreq driver in linux and reached upto  cpufreq_driver->target which is assigned for handling frequency change request. i searched for direct assembly instructions to do so but didn't find any.

Comment: Is this really a thing you want to do? Would it not be better to call the device driver that manages CPU frequency? There must be one since Windows can set power profiles.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the msr cpu register. For AMD cpu there is the open source project turion power control. It needs winring0.dll. There is also the windows app cpumsr and the LLA Driver by Andreas Valisky but it's very old and not supported and the website is offline. Winring0.dll isn't supported because it's too expensive.